# Notify user when they are added or removed from aws sso groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudtrail, aws-sso

I am trying to publish two specific cloudtrail events in s3

Event names:
AddMemberToGroup
RemoveMemberFromGroup

I am unable to find options to just store these two event logs in s3 buxket. Both logs and s3 bucket are in same account. Later I will use these events from s3 as trigger to lambda function which will extract member_id and group_id from the log. The member_id will be mapped to actual email id and email will be sent via sns. Please help me to create a trail with only 2 events which can be published to s3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can create a trail which only sends those events. I think you have to have the trail send all events, and do the filtering in the lambda (which is bad because you'll trigger a lot of unnecessary lambda invocations. :( )

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this architecture with the help of lambda function and event bridge rules.

So the cloudtrail logs are utilized by event bridge to filter out desired logs.
I created below rule to filter out `AddMemberToGroup` and `RemoveMemberFromGroup`:

```
{
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "source": ["aws.sso-directory"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["sso-directory.amazonaws.com"],
    "errorCode": [{
      "exists": false
    }],
    "eventName": ["RemoveMemberFromGroup", "AddMemberToGroup"]
  }
}
```

The target of this event bridge was set to lambda function. This lambda function checked if the event is same as `AddMemberToGroup` and `RemoveMemberFromGroup`, it fetched the name of the sso group and member details. These details were sent via email using Simple email service.

Lambda Code:

```
import json
import boto3
import logging   
import os

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def get_group_name(identitystore_client,group_id):
try:
    response = identitystore_client.describe_group(IdentityStoreId='d-123xyzabc12',GroupId=group_id)
    print(f"group metadata:{response}")
    groupname  = response['DisplayName']
    return groupname
except Exception as e:
    LOGGER.error(f"Error retrieving member name: {str(e)}")
    return None

def get_member_name(identitystore_client,member_id):
try:
    response = identitystore_client.describe_user(IdentityStoreId='d-123xyzabc12',UserId=member_id)
    print(f"User metadata:{response}")
    membername  = response['UserName']
    displayname = response['DisplayName']
    print(displayname)
    return [membername,displayname]
except Exception as e:
    LOGGER.error(f"Error retrieving member name: {str(e)}")
    return None

def lambda_handler(event, context):
LOGGER.info(event)

ses = boto3.client('ses')
identitystore_client = boto3.client('identitystore')

source_email = 'provide your source email'
EmailArn='pls provide your email arn'
destination_emails = ['provide your destination mail id']


request_parameters = event.get('detail', {}).get('requestParameters', {})
group_id = str(request_parameters.get('groupId'))
print(f'group id type - {type(group_id)}')
print(f'groupId:{group_id}')
event_name = str(event.get('detail', {}).get('eventName'))
if event_name == 'AddMemberToGroup':
    member_id = str(request_parameters.get('member',{}).get('memberId'))
    print(f'member id type - {type(member_id)}')
    print(f'member_id:{member_id}')
else:
    member_id = str(request_parameters.get('memberId'))
    print(f'member id type - {type(member_id)}')
    print(f'member_id:{member_id}')

member_name = str(get_member_name(identitystore_client,member_id))
group_name = str(get_group_name(identitystore_client,group_id))

email_content = f"""
<p align="left">Dear team,</br></br>
There is a change :</br></br>
<b>Event Name</b>: {event_name}</br>
<b>User</b>: {member_name}</br>
<b>LDAP Group</b>: {group_name}</br>
"""

# Send the email using SES
if 'admin' in group_name.lower():
    ses.send_email(
        Source=source_email,
        SourceArn=EmailArn,
        Destination={'ToAddresses': destination_emails},
        Message={
            'Subject': {'Data': 'Alert!!!'},
            'Body': {'Html': {'Data':email_content}}
        }
    )

return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
}
```